# Gradle dependencies recursively

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, gradlew

I have multiple repositories that each have a gradle project and in turn submodules. The structure looks like this

```
**repo1**
 -build.gradle
 -components
  --module1
    ---module1.gradle
    ---src/main/java*
  --module2
    ---module2.gradle
    ---src/main/java*

**repo2**
 -build.gradle
 -components
  --module3
    ---module3.gradle
    ---src/main/java*
  --module4
    ---module4.gradle
    ---src/main/java*
```

Each of these repo can depend on another. Now I want to build a dependency graph of these repo/modules. How can I do that recursively so that I have the entire dep tree?

I have tried

- gradle dependencies
- gradle module1:dependencies
- Analyse dependency option in Intellij

None of these works properly.